# Clear Time zone cached data on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I change Time zone from device settings, I want the dates in my application to reflect the current timezone. However, as soon as I change the Time zone and launch my app from recent apps, TimeZoneInfo.Local still represents the previous Time zone. It's only when I relaunch my app that the new Time zone gets reflected.

I read it in may threads that .NET caches Time zone information and we need to call the following methods to clear it: 
- CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
- TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();

However, these methods are not defined for Windows Phone 8 SDK. Can someone please help me in case I am missing anything.

Thank-you

Comment: did you find an answer to this? also, even after a restart, the change in region is not reflected in RegionInfo.CurrentRegion... any ideas?